# Calling function after every 24hrs without affecting following code

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, timer, python-multithreading

```
from threading import Timer    

def Add():
  ...Some process...
  Timer(86400, Add).start() ## 86400 secs in 24 hours.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Add()

  "Consuming Kafka Messages and will run continously once started".
```

Once the code runs Add function is called and program starts to consume kafka messages and waits for it continously. I want to call the "Add" function every 24 hrs without disturbing kafka process. For this I have tried one threading.timer but I am not sure will it work or not.

I have one more question- is this thread initialize every 24hrs or it one thread just calls every 24 hrs.

Please advice I am doing correct and will it work or not and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an extra function that calls `add()` and adds the timer for you, something like this:

```
def task1():
    while True:
        add()
        time.sleep(86400)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target=task1)
    thread.start()
    # add kafka code
```

Comment: from threading import Thread
import time

def add():
  print("Thread from a function")

def threaded_function():
  while True:
    time.sleep(86400)
    add()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  thread = Thread(target = threaded_function)
  thread.start()
  ...Rest of the kafka Code Here...

Something like this??